# Vertical alignment between the choices

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment, tasks

I want to adjust the vertical alignment between A and D, B and E.

[image]

I want it to be like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=4.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\taskindent}
\settowidth{\taskindent}{\text{m)}}
\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
}

\begin{document}
        \textbf{I want to adjust the vertical alignment between A and D, B and E.}
\begin{tasks}(5)
                \task*(2) text
                \task*(2) text
                \task text
                \task*(2) text
                \task text
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the actual question is

Comment: I want to increase the vertical distance between choices @cgnieder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `after-item-skip` for the distance between rows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=4.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
  item-indent = 15pt ,
  label-width = 12pt ,
  column-sep = 10em ,  % <<< maybe use this instead of empty columns?
  label = \Alph*) ,
  after-skip = 3ex ,
  after-item-skip = 2cm % <<< between rows
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
  \task text
  \task text
  \task text
  \task text
  \task text
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]